# Guess a random number between 1 and 100

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, number-guessing-game

I want some recommendations or something I could add to the game. Please tell me what I could do better or what I did wrong. I made this during the time I learned Python.

```
import random
num = random.randint(1, 100)
while True:
    print('Guess a number between 1 and 100')
    guess = input()
    i = int(guess)
    if i == num:
        print('You won!!!')
        break
    elif i < num:
               print('Try Higher')
    elif i > num:
               print('Try Lower')
#any recommendations for the game end
print('if you gussed less than 6 times you won')
```

Comment: One improvement would be to have the program automatically count the number of tries, so it can tell the user whether they won or lost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Proper integer conversion

Right now, as it stands, you're just converting any user input to a integer, using the `int` function. What do you suppose happens if the user enters something like `"abc"`?

What you need to do is set up a [`try`-`except`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) block, like this:

```
try:
    user_integer = input("Enter an integer: ")
    user_integer = int(user_integer)
except ValueError:
    print("You must enter a valid integer!")
```

To set up something like this in your code, you'd change your code to something like this:

```
...

while True:
    print("Guess a number between 1 and 100.")
    guess = input()

    try:
        integer_guess = int(guess):

        ...
    except ValueError:
        ...
```

---

## Tracking the number of "rounds"/"tries"

Rather than printing a message saying that if the user got below a certain amount of tries, they win, you can implement it into the code. The easiest way to do this would be to use a `for ... in range( ... )` loop, like this:

```
rounds = ...
for _ in range(rounds):
    ...
```

*(This has been implemented below, for reference.)*

---

## Design

This is not a very extensible design, again, I'd recommend creating a function that allows you to create custom games, like this:

```
def number_guessing_game(low, high, rounds):
    print("Guess a number between {low} and {high}. You have {rounds} rounds to try and guess correctly.".format(low=low, high=high, rounds=rounds))
    number = random.randint(low, high)

    for _ in range(rounds):
        guess = input("Enter an integer: ")

        try:
            integer = int(guess)
            if integer == number:
                print('You won!!!')
                return
            elif integer < number:
                print('Try Higher')
            elif integer > number:
                print('Try Lower')

        except ValueError:
            print("You must enter a valid integer.")

    print("You didn't guess correctly in {rounds} rounds. You lost.".format(rounds=rounds))
```

An example function call might look like this:

```
number_guessing_game(1, 100, 6)
```

---

In short, all of your code becomes the following:

```
import random

def number_guessing_game(low, high, rounds):
    print("Guess a number between {low} and {high}. You have {rounds} rounds to try and guess correctly.".format(low=low, high=high, rounds=rounds))
    number = random.randint(low, high)

    for _ in range(rounds):
        guess = input("Enter an integer: ")

        try:
            integer = int(guess)
            if integer == number:
                print('You won!!!')
                return
            elif integer < number:
                print('Try Higher')
            elif integer > number:
                print('Try Lower')

        except ValueError:
            print("You must enter a valid integer.")

    print("You didn't guess correctly in {rounds} rounds. You lost.".format(rounds=rounds))

number_guessing_game(1, 100, 6)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Typing an invalid integer probably shouldn't count towards the 6 guesses. Also I'd reveal the correct number if the player loses.

Comment: You should keep the `try:` block as small as possible as a rule; preferably only containing the operation we are interested in. In this case, the `try: except: else:` construction, putting the `if: elif: elif` test in the `else` clause, would fit well (in the initial example, the `input` call should be outside the `try` clause on the same grounds). An alternative to `else` would be to use `continue` within the `except` clause, which also saves an indentation level by an early exit on invalid input (note the above comment on handling non-integer convertable inputs, though).

Answer (score 5):

```
guess = input()
i = int(guess)
```

Why are you splitting this on to two different lines? You can just merge the `int()` onto the line above it, and pass `input()` into it like this:

```
guess = int(input())
```

---

As [Greg Hewgill](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/9717/greg-hewgill) mentioned in the comments, rather than saying this:

```
print('if you gussed less than 6 times you won')
```

You should actually count up and tell the user if they won.

This can be done by using a simple counter for how many times the user has made an attempt. Then, every time the code loops (they enter an answer), you just increment the counter:

```
num = random.randint(1, 100)
attempts = 0
while True:
    attempts += 1
```

Then, at the end of your code and after the loop, you just need to set up some simple conditionals that check the `attempts` variable:

```
if attempts < 6:
    print("You won!")
else:
    print("You lost!")
```

Then, to take this step further and reduce [magic numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad), create a **constant** at the top of your code that defines the number of attempts at which the user has lost.

That is done like this:

```
ATTEMPTS_FOR_LOSE = 6
```

Then, you just substitute the `6` for `ATTEMPTS_FOR_LOST` in the conditional snippet I showed a little above.